# Override Magento_Ui modal-popup.html file

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, template, magento-2.1.7, modal-popup

I need to override the `modal-popup.html` file in my custom theme (I want to remove the "Continue" button).

I've tried to create the following directory in the theme's directory:

```
argento-essence-custom/Magento_Ui/view/base/web/templates/modal
```

and then i ran on CLI

```
setup:static-content:deploy
cache:flush
```

but it didn't work, 
Thank you in advance for the help.

**Theme:** local custom version of argento-essence.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Did you delete the static file located at:

`/pub/static/frontend/{Vendor}/{ThemeName}/en_US/Magento_Ui/templates/modal/modal-popup.html`

Also, in your post you are referencing `.phtml`, when that particular file is a `.html` file.

Maybe that is the problem.

Magento will automatically pull / move / symlink the static file if it doesn't exist in pub/static. No need to do a full redeploy.

Comment: I've used the correct file extension ("html"), i wrote it wrong here; i've deleted the file too but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem the solution it to copy it into:

`<Theme_Dir>/Magento_Ui/web/templates/modal/modal-popup.html`